# what is the usefulness of '>' in python 

Tags: python

```
print 'xxx' > 'ssaww'
```

it print 'true'

who can give me a clear example .

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like in math, `>` compares two operands and returns True if the left operand is greater than the right, otherwise False.

Answer (score 4):

In python strings are ordered [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Answer (score 3):

you can test it out on the interpreter

```
>>> 'xxx'>'yyy'  #first character 'x' is less than first character 'y', so false
False
>>> 'xxx'>'xyy' 
False
>>> 'xyy'>'xyx' #3rd character 'y' is greater than 3rd character 'x', so true
True
```

Answer (score 0):

to order strings syntactically (e.g. alphabetically).

Answer (score 0):

It can do 
y>x>z 
as a nicer way to say y>x and x>z.

As others have mentioned its a simple greater-than comparison (in your case for strings).